# LINQ to select Leads where FirstName.length < 6

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Which LINQ will select Leads where FirstName.length < 6?

This query throws "Invalid 'where' Condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method"

```LINQ
var q = from a in serviceC.LeadSet where a.FirstName.Length < 6 select a;
```

Comment: Maybe related http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2012/04/04/notsupportedexception-invalid-where-condition-an-entity-member-is-invoking-an-invalid-property-or-method.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter It does list the LINQ to CRM Limitation that Bvrce is violating, but the solution specified is not possible if Brvce does need to get the leads where the first name is less than 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that all Linq to CRM Statements are converted into Query Expressions, and Query Expression don't support a length operator.  This leaves you with a couple options.

1. Use a direct SQL query to get the data you need.  This is less than desirable for most situations since you're operating outside of the SDK, and not possible if you're using CRM Online
2. Use Grant's answer to actually look at the length, which unfortunetly does pull all of the records...
3. Try this totally untested idea I just came up with:  Query Expression do have a GreaterEqual condition so you should be able to compare it to a string of 6 single quotes (since single quotes are the first character when sorted by default.  So theoretically, this should work:

```
var q = from a in serviceC.LeadSet where a.FirstName <= "''''''" select a;
```

### EDIT

After performing a test I realized that Linq won't accept that Expression, even though SQL will.  So the answer is to create the actual Query Expression:

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("lead");
qe.Criteria.AddCondition("firstname", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, "''''''");

var entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ToList` to project the collection to objects, that should do it.

Comment: That would result in the entire database table being transferred to the client and the filter being done on the client. This won't scale.

Comment: @JimWooley I know. Well, actually, not the _entire_ database necessarily, but the point is potential heavy loading.